# Flex error Server.Acknowledge.Failed: Didn't receive an acknowledge message

Tags: c#, flex4, arrays, fluorinefx

I'm having a very strange behavior with a C# class 'Digital', mapped to an AS3 class (Flex) with the same name, using FluorineFx.

This class (C#) has a FluorineFx.AMF3.ByteArray field, mapped with a ByteArray property in AS3, it's purpose is transmit binary files stored in databases.

Sometimes (not always) I'm receiving this error: "Server.Acknowledge.Failed - Didn't receive an acknowledge message - Was expecting mx.messaging.messages.AcknowledgeMessage, but received null." This error never occurs in development machines, just in clients over the network.

Debbuging with Firebug/FlashFirebug, this exception is thrown randomically:

RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds.
at ObjectInput/readObject()
at mx.collections::ArrayList/readExternal()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\collections\ArrayList.as:593] 
at mx.collections::ArrayCollection/readExternal()[E:\dev\hero_private\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\collections\ArrayCollection.as:149]

This is driving me crazy, I know generally this is caused by a mapping mistake, but if it's the case, it should ocurrs always and everywhere.

Any help I will appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm embarrassed, but maybe this could help somebody else: the real problema was the Firewall in those machines. In some cases, Personal ZoneAlarm and in others, Windows Firewall. It really makes sense because the response with binary files embebed should be interrupted to protect the clients.